# static variable in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, variables, static

I have:

> 1. MyNameSpace.MyClass1
> 2. MyNameSpace.MyClass2

i need to get value from MyClass1.myvar1 from MyClass2.
Should I do that with static variable

What happens with variable value if it is static in a web application.
Im using MyClass1 as: `var mClass=new MyNameSpace.MyClass1()`, and from that im using mClass.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value context is global, than it is ok to use static variable. Remember that if the value is updated, its updated for all users. If the data is different or belong to a user, than never use static, instead instantiate object of `MyClass1` inside `MyClass2` method .

you can use following approach.

Declare `MyClass1.myvar1` as public and access from `MyClass2`.

```
class MyClass1{
public int myvar1 = 7;
}

class MyClass2{
 public void TestMethod(){
  MyClass1 obj = new MyClass1();
  int val = obj.myvar1; 
 }
}
```

In this case, your data is safe.

Comment: Question is "i need to get value from MyClass1.myvar1 from MyClass2". I dont think that using Session is answer to that.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not use a static variable here.  Remember, `static` means the variable is global for the application.  In ASP.Net, you have a single application instance that is shared among everyone who visits your site.  Using static variables can result in one user seeing another user's data.

Comment: Does that means that static var inside Class used like new Class(), is same value across all threads in asp.net web application ?

Comment: @sinisa yet, that's exactly what it means

Answer (score 1):

It is not OK to use a static variable within ASP.NET unless you take thread safety into account. A single request will generally run on a single thread. Different requests will probably run on different threads. (See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx for some good threading information.)

Unless you study up on writing thread safe code, I would consider using the following objects instead to maintain static data:

1. Application - for application-wide static data
2. Session - if it's user specific static data
3. HttpContext.Items - if it's data to be used by different objects within a single request
4. HttpRuntime.Cache / HttpContext.Cache - to cache shared data that can have expirations / dependencies

Answer (score 0):

All youneed is to make a new instance of your **class2** and call your variable from created instance in **class1** like

```
myclass1
{
    string Variable = string.empty;
    protected void YourMethod()
    {
        myclass2 c2 = new myclass2()
        this.Variable = c2.Variable;
    }
}
```